# I want to compare 3 different columns (B,C,D) values then want to get the higher value result in F column

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I have started VBA programming by google learning and making some macros to automate my work .
There is a range in which I want to compare values and whatever value is higher in each rows-columns  want to get print in F column:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim filrange As Range 
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set filrange = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

For Each cell In filrange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

  If cell.Value >= 10 And 
     (Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) >= 10 And 
     (Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) >= 10 Then

    cell.Offset(0, 3).Select

 End If
Next
```

Comment: So do you want the highest value in rows B, C & D?  Or only where B, C and D are all above 10?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Do Loop.

```
lastRow = Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 'the last row in your data in column B as I thought you referenced B, C and D
x = 1 'the starting row

Do While x <= lastRow
cells(x, 6).formula = "=Max(B" & x & ":D" & x & ")"
y = cells(x, 6)
cells(x, 6) = y
x = x + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.Offset(0, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(cell.Row, "B"),Cells(cell.Row, "D")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheet name if needed
        'Find the last row of columnA
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop column F from 1 to LastRow
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Application.Max(.Range("B" & i).Value, .Range("C" & i).Value, .Range("D" & i).Value)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]